# Issue modifying date on activated order due to work flow

Tags: api, process-builder, php

I use the PHP Toolkit to backdate orders as they are processed in our project management system, but I am having an issue recently where orderitems are not being updated as expected. I disabled the trigger flow and it worked flawlessly, but now that means our account managers will not have their scheduled tasks created to call back their customers each month.

The problem seems to be in condition one. The field is empty to begin with, but when I go back to update it, it fails to update, with the following message:

> The record couldn’t be saved because it failed to trigger a flow. A
>   flow trigger failed to execute the flow with version ID
>   301d0000000TTgA. Contact your administrator for help.
>
> CANNOT_EXECUTE_FLOW_TRIGGER

I deactivated the flow and it updated the dates as expected (AD_EXPIRATION_DATE__C, AD_START_DATE__C) via my PHP class.

I cannot understand why it seems to believe there is an issue because the date is being updated. The second condition, Status = Activated is already being met.

Here is an example:

[image]

**PHP Code**

```
$sObject1->AD_START_DATE__C = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("today"));
$sObject1->AD_EXPIRATION_DATE__C = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("30 days"));
```

**Debug Email**

```
An error occurred at element myRule_1_A1 (FlowRecordCreate).

The flow failed to access the value for myVariable_current.Order.Account.AccountManager__r.Id because it hasn't been set or assigned.
________________________________________
This report lists the elements that the flow interview executed. The report is a beta feature.

We welcome your feedback on IdeaExchange.

Flow Details
Flow Name: Renewal_Task
Type: Workflow
Version: 3
Status: Active

Flow Interview Details
Interview Label: Renewal_Task-3_OrderItem
Current User: **** ****** (***********)
Start time: 1/27/2016 7:48 AM
Duration: 0 seconds

How the Interview Started
**** ****** (***********) started the flow interview.
Some of this flow's variables were set when the interview started.
myVariable_old = 802d0000000TOSGAA4
myVariable_current = 802d0000000TOSGAA4

ASSIGNMENT: myVariable_waitStartTimeAssignment
{!myVariable_waitStartTimeVariable} Equals {!Flow.CurrentDateTime}
Result
{!myVariable_waitStartTimeVariable} = "1/27/2016 7:48 AM"

DECISION: myDecision
Executed this outcome: myRule_1
Outcome conditions: and
1. {!myVariable_current.Ad_Expiration_Date__c} (February 26, 2016) Greater than January 1, 2000
2. {!myVariable_current.Order.Status} (Activated) Equals Activated
Logic: All conditions must be true (AND)

DECISION: myRule_1_pmetdec
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the reason this flow was failing to process is because this particular account lacked an account manager. After adding the account manager, the flow operated as normal.